# returning a query with 3 table joins- one being an outer join

Tags: mysql, sql

i am building a car booking system, the query i need to build is one that displays all the cars in the system- but each car can be booked by 2 people at the same time.

I only want to display cars that have not been fully booked or only have been booked by a single person. I want to be able to see the persons first name and last name if it has been booked by a single person so others can tell who they will be driving with.

This is my query so far but its returning the first record multiple times

```
 SELECT cars.*, people.first_name, people.last_name 
FROM 
    cars 
LEFT JOIN booking on cars.id = booking.car LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON booking.person_1 = people.id
WHERE cars.id NOT IN 
(SELECT car
 FROM booking WHERE slot = 'morning_drive' AND dated = '2011-11-05' AND person_1 != '' AND person_2 != '') AND cars.type = '911'
```

Heres the structure of the three tables

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `large_img_url` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `small_img_url` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nr` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `license_plate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `exterior_color` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `interior_color` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PDK` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Manual` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('911','vintage') NOT NULL,
  `power` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;



CREATE TABLE `booking` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `slot` enum('morning_drive','afternoon_loop','return_drive') NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('911','vintage_911') NOT NULL,
  `car` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_1` int(11) default NULL,
  `person_2` int(11) default NULL,
  `dated` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;


CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `organisation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `event_date` date NOT NULL,
  `wave` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=454 ;
```

so how can i have my query only return one row per car basically, displaying only cars that have no (person_2) and no (person_1 or  person_2), if the car does have person_1- it will retrieve that persons first_name and last_name

**update**

i have figured out that the main select query is returning all the rows- i need it restricted to slot = 'morning_drive' AND dated = '2011-11-05' so it shows if a person has booked the car for that time slot but also it needs to return the cars where no user has booked for that timeslot

**update 2**

based on realising new requirements of the query i have added a left outer join subquery instead of using a full table-

```
 SELECT cars.*, people.first_name, people.last_name 
FROM 
    cars 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT car, person_1 FROM booking WHERE  slot = 'morning_drive' AND dated = '2011-11-05' AND booking.person_1 != '' AND booking.person_2 = '') bookings on cars.id = bookings.car LEFT  JOIN people ON bookings.person_1 = people.id
WHERE cars.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT car
 FROM booking WHERE slot = 'morning_drive' AND dated = '2011-11-05' AND person_1 != '' AND person_2 != '')
 AND cars.type = '911'
```

this is closer to what i want returned but its not join the people table first_names and last_names- its returning nothing

Comment: Did you try DISTINCT for unique record retrieval ?

Comment: yes i did, i tried it but its still returning multiple rows

Comment: @ChrisMccabe, the slot, dated and type criteria in your select appear to be unrelated to the criteria described in the question. Are these additional criteria?

Comment: Your existing setup will allow the same car to be booked by one person only multiple times - so for example, car X1 could be booked by John Smith only on one day, and Fred Brown only on another day. Your query would then return car X1 twice, once for John Smith and once for Fred Brown.

Comment: i have figured out that the main select query is returning all the rows- i need it restricted to  slot = 'morning_drive' AND dated = '2011-11-05' so it shows if a person has booked the car for that time slot but also it needs to return the cars where no user has booked for that timeslot

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT cars.*, people.first_name, people.last_name 
FROM cars 
JOIN booking on cars.id = booking.car
JOIN people on booking.person_1 = people.id
WHERE  booking.slot = 'morning_drive'     AND 
       booking.dated = '2011-11-05'       AND 
       coalesce(booking.person_2,'') = '' AND 
       cars.type = '911'
UNION
SELECT cars.*, '' first_name, '' last_name 
FROM cars
WHERE  cars.type = '911' AND 
       NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT NULL FROM booking 
        WHERE slot = 'morning_drive' AND 
              dated = '2011-11-05'   AND 
              cars.id = bookings.car)
```